# getting dates closest to today in C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# list containing dates of events. I like to know how I can use lamdas to get the latest events ordered.

Here is my existing code for the event class.

```
    /// <summary>
/// Class that represents an Info Session. 
/// </summary>
public class InfoSessions {
    public String Place { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public InfoSessions(String place, DateTime date)
    {
        Place = place;
        Date = date;
    }
}
```

This is what I currently have to order the events. I don't want to see past events.

```
List<InfoSessions> sessions = new List<InfoSessions>();
sessions.Add(new InfoSessions("Melbourne", new DateTime(2015,03,24)));
sessions.Add(new InfoSessions("HongKong", new DateTime(2015, 02, 14)));
sessions.Add(new InfoSessions("Singapore", new DateTime(2015, 04, 14)));
sessions.Add(new InfoSessions("Sydney", new DateTime(2015, 05, 18)));
sessions.Add(new InfoSessions("Aukland", new DateTime(2015, 08, 18)));

List<InfoSessions> orderSessions = sessions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();
InfoSessionGrid.DataSource = orderSessions;
InfoSessionGrid.DataBind();
```

I like to get events ordered in immediate occurrence by date.

Comment: could you elaborate what input and output you want?

Comment: It is spelt "Auckland".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, you simply need to add a `Where()` predicate to eliminate anything prior to a specified date. Check this example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sessions = new List<InfoSessions>();
        sessions.Add(new InfoSessions("South Pole", new DateTime(2015, 01, 01)));
        sessions.Add(new InfoSessions("Melbourne", new DateTime(2015, 03, 24)));
        sessions.Add(new InfoSessions("HongKong", new DateTime(2015, 02, 14)));
        sessions.Add(new InfoSessions("Singapore", new DateTime(2015, 04, 14)));
        sessions.Add(new InfoSessions("Sydney", new DateTime(2015, 05, 18)));
        sessions.Add(new InfoSessions("Auckland", new DateTime(2015, 08, 18)));

        var orderSessions = sessions.Where(x => x.Date > DateTime.Now)
                                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                                    .ToList();

        orderSessions.ForEach(x=> Console.WriteLine("Location: {0}, Date: {1}", x.Place, x.Date));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class InfoSessions
{
    public String Place { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public InfoSessions(String place, DateTime date)
    {
        Place = place;
        Date = date;
    }
}
```

I've excluded anything that happened before now, so the South Pole session doesn't get included in the list.

Note that you spelt `Auckland` wrong (sorry, it's my home town so I couldn't let it go), and you might want `OrderBy` to meet your criteria of *ordered in immediate occurrence by date*.

Comment: Hah, sorry didn't see your answer before I commented.  Damn its hot here today eh bro?